# Как хранить заготовленный C# Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, словари

У меня есть около десяти тысяч строчек в таблице следующего формата:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

id может быть буквенное.

Нужно в программе на C# уметь сопоставлять для id соответствующую ему group.

Для этого я хочу создать dictionary и по ключу id доставать значение group (как value). Но данных у меня очень много (порядка 10 тысяч строчек). Поэтому два вопроса:

1. Насколько эффективен такой подход? Использование словаря. Может есть что-то удобнее?
2. Если все-таки использовать словарь, как его заранее подключить к программе? Внешним классом?

Спасибо!

Comment: 1. Ефективность - не ручаюсь,  проще всего сохранить/восстановить - сериализация. 2. Если вы хотите ускорится - думаю лучший вариант - используя СУБД.

Comment: Альтернатива Dictionary - DataTable + создание первичного ключа. Возможно это будет быстрее чем Dictionary. Функция сохранения в DataTable встроена в отличии от Dictionary.

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо! СУБД прикручивать не хотелось бы - слишком маленькая программка. Окей, со структурами данных я поняла: Dictionary или DataTable - спасибо.
А на счет того, как добавить данных в проект? xml-файл? Инициализировать напрямую внутри проекта?..

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable/) есть интересная статья по поводу работы колекций из стандартной библиотеки.

Самый очевидный конкурент Dictionary - Hashtable.

Можно выделить, что Dictionary хорошо работает с вставкой элементов при большом размере самой колекции. При этом, Hashtable хорош при поиске элементов.

---

В целом, использование словаря - оптимальный вариант.

Так же в интернете полно примеров подключения c# к excel. Вот, например:

```
string con =
  @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\temp\test.xls;" + 
  @"Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";    
using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection); 
    using(OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
         while(dr.Read())
         {
             var row1Col0 = dr[0];
             Console.WriteLine(row1Col0);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Мне вообще не придется изменять данные - это статическая таблица. Подскажите, пожалуйста, а каким способом данные можно загрузить в hashtable? Т.е. как подключить эту огромную статическую таблицу к программе?

Comment: Так вышло, что я как раз дополнил сообщение) Это примерный кусочек кода для конекции с таблицей

Comment: Спасибо :) Но мне не хотелось бы хранить это во внешнем файле, хочется зашить это внутрь исполняемого файла. Поэтому я думала на счет какого-нибудь xml-формата или прямой инициализации... Нет ли каких-либо стандартных подходов к этому? Или лучше просто подключить excel к проекту?

Comment: Можно распарсить всё данные в СУБД таблицы. Для этого можно использовать SqlLite, например. Но, на самом деле, просто тянуть excel таблицу в билд - не самый плохой подход) Писать это в xml - дело не благодарное, нужно делать дополнительные парсеры, а ситуации, по сути, это не изменит.

Answer (score 1):

1. Да, использование словаря наиболее удобно. Словарь и есть «материализованное» отображение одного множества на другое. Более эффективным может быть просто массив, если ваши ключи — последовательные целые числа.
2. Как угодно.

   - Если данных мало, то обычно проще всего задать литерал вида `var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>() { [1] = "one", [2] = "two" };`. Вы можете пойти этим путём, но файл с исходником вам, вероятно, придётся сгенерировать одноразовым скриптом.
   - Другой вариант — данные в сериализованном виде (например, XML или JSON, или хотя вы CSV) в файл, и распарсить их при старте программы. Файл, вероятно, лучше положить в ресурсы:

   [image: вот сюдамана божольде]